# Range expanding in quickstart xlwings on mac

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwings

Trying to get familiar with xlwings on my mac (nl version) and working through the quickstart document.

I can read/write to a single cel.However, when I try the example from the quick start document I get an complicated error.
The command is:

`sht.range('A1').value = [['Foo 1', 'Foo 2', 'Foo 3'], [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]]`

I cannot solve it and had expected that `sht.range('A1').expand().value` would give me:

`[['Foo 1', 'Foo 2', 'Foo 3'], [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]]`

The complete error message is:

```
EventError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py in __call__(self, *args, **kargs)
    481                 try:
--> 482                         return self.AS_appdata.target().event(self._code, params, atts, codecs=self.AS_appdata).send(timeout, sendflags)
    483                 except aem.EventError as e:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa/aem/aemsend.py in send(self, timeout, flags)
     91                                                         errormsg = _defaultcodecs.unpack(errormsg)
---> 92                                                 raise EventError(errornum, errormsg, eventresult)
     93                                 if kae.keyAEResult in eventresult: # application has returned a value

EventError: Command failed: The object you are trying to access does not exist (-1728)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

CommandError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-5623573f98f7> in <module>
----> 1 sht.range('A1').value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py in value(self, data)
   1523     @value.setter
   1524     def value(self, data):
-> 1525         conversion.write(data, self, self._options)
   1526 
   1527     def expand(self, mode='table'):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/conversion/__init__.py in write(value, rng, options)
     41     pipeline = accessors.get(convert, convert).router(value, rng, options).writer(options)
     42     ctx = ConversionContext(rng=rng, value=value)
---> 43     pipeline(ctx)
     44     return ctx.value

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/conversion/framework.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65         for stage in self:
---> 66             stage(*args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/conversion/standard.py in __call__(self, ctx)
     58             scalar = ctx.meta.get('scalar', False)
     59             if not scalar:
---> 60                 ctx.range = ctx.range.resize(len(ctx.value), len(ctx.value[0]))
     61 
     62             self._write_value(ctx.range, ctx.value, scalar)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py in resize(self, row_size, column_size)
   1700             column_size = self.shape[1]
   1701 
-> 1702         return Range(self(1, 1), self(row_size, column_size)).options(**self._options)
   1703 
   1704     def offset(self, row_offset=0, column_offset=0):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py in __init__(self, cell1, cell2, **options)
    993         if impl is None:
    994             if cell2 is not None and isinstance(cell1, Range) and isinstance(cell2, Range):
--> 995                 if cell1.sheet != cell2.sheet:
    996                     raise ValueError("Ranges are not on the same sheet")
    997                 impl = cell1.sheet.range(cell1, cell2).impl

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py in __ne__(self, other)
    785 
    786     def __ne__(self, other):
--> 787         return not self.__eq__(other)
    788 
    789     def __hash__(self):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py in __eq__(self, other)
    782 
    783     def __eq__(self, other):
--> 784         return isinstance(other, Sheet) and self.book == other.book and self.name == other.name
    785 
    786     def __ne__(self, other):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py in name(self)
    793     def name(self):
    794         """Gets or sets the name of the Sheet."""
--> 795         return self.impl.name
    796 
    797     @name.setter

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py in name(self)
    306     @property
    307     def name(self):
--> 308         return self.xl.name.get()
    309 
    310     @name.setter

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py in __call__(self, *args, **kargs)
    516                                                 return
    517                                         raise CommandError(self, (args, kargs), e, self.AS_appdata) from e
--> 518                         raise CommandError(self, (args, kargs), e, self.AS_appdata) from e
    519 
    520         def AS_formatcommand(self, args):

CommandError: Command failed:
        OSERROR: -1728
        MESSAGE: The object you are trying to access does not exist
        COMMAND: app(pid=62804).workbooks['**Map2**'].worksheets['**Sheet**'].name.get()
```

Comment: What is the error you get? When in doubt, show the full traceback. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error message suggests that one object (most likely the workbookname `Map2` or the sheet name `Sheet` do not exist. Try to close Excel and start from scratch to see if the error persists or post a *full* code example to replicated. It would also be helpful to say that you are on a Mac.

Comment: I am on a mac and use office in NL version. When I open a workbook the default name is "map*". If I use it on a existing workbook and use the appropriate name for the tab (blad1) it works!. What i do not understand that     sht = wb.sheets('Sheet') (although the sheet name is "blad1") and sht.range("A1").value = 1 is ok but i get the error when i try with a list.

Comment: had the exact issue in jupyter notebook and code works fine after switching to spyder